# Examples of good multithreaded Java code?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to study some good multi-threaded Java code. Could anyone please suggest some examples ? Is Apache web server a good pick ?

Thanks,
Abhinav.

Answer (score 15):

I'd recommend you to have a look at this [book](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/). It covers almost everything about java and
concurrency/multithreading, including coding principles and many examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am currently studying from "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming". However, I would like to study some real world code also besides examples in books.

Comment: What kind of application are you looking for? Multithreaded network servers, parallel computations, GUI interactions, etc.?

Comment: I read some sections from Java Concurrency in Practice, its a very nice book to have. I was looking for some real world code that was built to handle large number of threads, maintain safety and perform well. So, maybe multithreaded network servers ?

Answer (score 8):

I would strongly recommend you read - at least twice - (I am on my 4th reading now) the superb [The secrets of Concurrency](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue146.html) that [Dr. Heinz M. Kabutz](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/) has generously made public on his website.

Topics include:

[The Law of the Sabotaged Doorbell](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue146.html)
[The Law of the Distracted Spearfisherman](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue147.html)
[The Law of the Overstocked Haberdashery](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue149.html)
[The Law of the Blind Spot](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue150.html)
[The Law of the Leaked Memo](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue151.html)
[The Law of the Corrupt Politician](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue152.html)
[The Law of the Micromanager](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue155.html)
[The Law of Cretan Driving](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue156.html)
[The Law of Sudden Riches](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue159.html)
[The Law of the Uneaten Lutefisk](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue160.html)
[The Law of the Xerox Copier](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue176.html)

All are both entertaining and extremely informative.

Where else but in the [Overstocked Haberdashery](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue149.html) will you find code like:

```
public class ThreadCreationTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final AtomicInteger threads_created = new AtomicInteger(0);
    while (true) {
      final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
      new Thread() {
        { start(); }
        public void run() {
          latch.countDown();
          synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("threads created: " +
                threads_created.incrementAndGet());
            try {
              wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
          }
        }
      };
      latch.await();
    }
  }
}
```

where he not only uses a `CountDownLatch` **and** an `AtomicInteger` **and** `synchronized(this)` **and** handles an `InterruptedException` apropriately, he even uses a `double brace initialiser` to start the thread!! Now if that is not **epic java** what is?

Answer (score 1):

Best tutorial about concurreny in Java ever

[The Java Memory Model](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTVooKLLVT8)

Comment: The link doesn't work. Can you update?

Comment: @John Fixed. Though I am not sure how relevant this link is anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Anything new you would suggest then?

Answer (score 1):

Doug Lea's [Concurrent Doubly Linked List](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ConcurrentDoublyLinkedList.htm) is an excellent example of `Lock Free` coding.

Answer (score 0):

In the [concurrency tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) you find the aspects like

- synchronization
- deadlocks
- as well as basic concepts

discussed.
If you wan't to how this is used in a real application have look at [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/concurrency-control.html)